# Get jqplot canvas object and convert to SVG

Tags: canvas, svg, plot, jqplot

How can i get the canvas object from a jqplot instance and then convert this to a svg object? something like that:

```
var myPlot = $.jqplot('plotdiv',  [[[1, 2],[3,5.12]]]);
var myPlotCanvas = myPlot.getCanvas();
var myPlotSVG = canvasToSVG(myPlotCanvas);
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any `canvasToSVG` method in jqPlot and since canvas is a pixel graphic and svg a vector one, your only solution is to replace all the drawing method used to compose your canvas image and convert them in valid svg elements : Hard time coming

Comment: I know there is no such method, and in theory I just need to get the canvas object generated by jqPlot, then I take care of converting the canvas object to its corresponding definition in svg, so, how can do that?

Comment: Hum  `document.querySelector('canvas')`. But I'm rather interested in how you will translate it to an svg :-)

Comment: PS: who ever wrote this "theory", don't trust him anymore.

Comment: jqplot normally generates multiple canvases. just to name an example: the line of a line chart is drawn on one canvas, the shadow of that line on another an any part of the graph again on a different canvas.

Despite any problems with converting to svg, there is no single canvas you could convert - you'd have to get all of them.